Probability of picking opposite sides of a unit square
The unit square is the square spanned by the points $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0)$, and $(1, 1)$ in the plane. Two points are chosen uniformly on the perimeter of the unit square. Find the probability that the points are on opposing faces of the unit square.
So what I have tried is:
Since $2$ points form $1$ side of a unit square and
since there is $4$ sides then one side is:
$P$(one side) = $1/4$
Opposing sides would have to be $1/4 \cdot 1/4 = 1/16$
Since there is $2$ pairs of opposing sides:
$1/16 + 1/16 = 1/8$
Is my path correct here?

Hint: by the symmetry of the square, you can assume that the first point is always on a fixed side (say the segment from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$).

I suppose both points are picked independently from one another. Name then $p_1$ and $p_2$ and there are four sides $S_j$ ($j=1,2,3,4$). You are looking for $P((p_1,p_2) \in (S_1 \times S_3) \cup (S_2 \times S_4) \cup (S_3 \times S_1) \cup (S_4 \times S_2)),$ then use additivity and conclude (the answer is $1/4$.

@WilliamM. Thank you. That was my idea.
